# Is there a free maps API like Bing/Google maps that can be used in internal applications

Tags: wpf, google-maps, maps, bing-maps

The licenses for both of the above allow certain free use but not for my requirements. I need a map API that can be used to find a place by postcode, then narrow down the position of a specific building to obtain the lat/long. The customer doesn't technically need this but it will make the locating of their store lat/longs easier. The very low usage involved doesn't warrant a paid subscription, as we are expecting up to 25 store position look ups per year.

Will be using the solution from WPF, though a browser-based option is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is http://www.openstreetmap.org/

but I have not used is until yet

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API

Comment: Can you explain how this API allows you to perform a reliable geocode operation?

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is perform a geocode operation over a maps platform.
There is currently no free platform that would allow to do so in an internal application.

There are several platforms that will allow you to use it in your internal application with dedicated licensing model and with adapted restrictions:

- **Bing Maps for Enterprise**: has known users or transaction based licensing models as well as a WPF Control: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html
- **Here Platform** (from Nokia): has known users model: http://developer.here.com/plans

Google does not provide a known user for internal application out of the licensing of the JavaScript API that might not be the best option to integrate in your WPF control (without using WebBrowser control and interop code).

OpenStreetMap also had limitations regarding the Licence that applies which was Share-A-Like, now it's ODBL and you should be able to use this project but the license only apply to the database, not the service that might be exposed (hosted) by tiers company. You might be interested in CloudMade offers.

Answer (score 0):

I still think Bing will be suitable for your situation. I think what you are looking for is the [Bing Search Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980849.aspx).

Using this, you can construct a [StructuredSearchQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc981064.aspx) to obtain the results of the place (which will be your [Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966816.aspx)), which should contain the Lat/Lon that you are after.

Have a look at the Microsoft example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980960.aspx).

The licensing is the same as for the Bing Maps control, so with your expected lookups range, it should be free for you to use.

Comment: Internal application use won't be free in terms of licensing.

Comment: @Nicolas - You're right. Having a look at the key information, it would most likely fall under the "Business asset management" category. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx)

Comment: Business asset management is dedicated to the tracking of asset.
Internal application is more related to known user licence model.